# Why does wikipedia define $G$ invariant polynomials this way?

Tags: invariant-theory

Why does wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_theory) define it as:

$$(g \cdot f)(x) := f(g^{-1}(x))?$$
Instead of,
$$ (g \cdot f)(x) := f(g(x)).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with making sure that compositions work in the correct order, so that
$$
(g_1 g_2) \cdot f = g_1 \cdot ( g_2 \cdot f).
\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
These conditions are equivalent to the fact that the representation $\pi: G \to GL(k[V])$ associated to the group action is in fact a group homomorphism:
$$
\pi(g_1g_2) = \pi(g_1) \, \pi(g_2). 
$$
Let's verify (\ref{1}), using the definition
$$
(g \cdot f) (x) = f( g^{-1} \cdot x)
$$
Calculate for all $x \in V$:
\begin{align}
(g_1g_2 \cdot f) (x) 
&= f \bigl( (g_1g_2)^{-1} \cdot x \bigr) \\ 
&= f \bigl( (g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}) \cdot x \bigr) \\
&= f \bigl( g_2^{-1} \cdot (g_1^{-1} \cdot x) \bigr) \\
&= (g_2 \cdot f)\, ( g_1^{-1} \cdot x) \\
&= \bigl( g_1 \cdot (g_2 \cdot f) \bigr) \, (x)
\end{align}

It works! The left action on $V$ (the source of the functions in $k[V]$) naturally becomes a *right* action on the space $k[V]$, so if we want it to be a left action, then we act by inverses.

---

Another way to see this it to draw everything in terms of compositions of functions. An element $g \in G$ acts by precomposition on functions $f \in k[V]$:
$$
V \xrightarrow{f} k 
\qquad \longmapsto \qquad 
V \xrightarrow{g^{-1}} V \xrightarrow{f} k
$$
so the element $g_1g_2 \in G$ acts by
$$
V \xrightarrow{f} k 
\qquad \longmapsto \qquad 
V \xrightarrow{g_1^{-1}} V \xrightarrow{g_2^{-1}} V \xrightarrow{f} k
$$
which is the same as
$$
V \xrightarrow{(g_1g_2)^{-1}} V \xrightarrow{f} k
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you define it as the latter one, then you may got
$$
((g_{1}g_{2})\cdot f)(x) = f((g_{1}g_{2})x) = (g_{1}\cdot f)(g_{2}x) = (g_{2}\cdot (g_{1}\cdot f))(x),
$$
which gives $(g_{1}g_{2})\cdot f = g_{2}\cdot (g_{1}\cdot f)$. One needs to include inverse to make $(g_{1}g_{2})\cdot f = g_{1}\cdot (g_{2}\cdot f)$.